# -fno-objc-arc flag set but ARC conversion is still trying to convert file in iOS

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert my project to arc.  I have set the -fno-objc-arc for all files that I want excluded from arc.  I then go to edit > convert to objective-c arc and the conversion process still attempts to convert them.  They fail conversion and hault me from moving forward.

Does anyone know what I can do to have the conversion process recognize my do not convert flag (-fno-objc-arc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select **Edit -> Refactor -> Convert To Objective-C ARC** first, then select the target to convert, then expand the target and un-check any source files you do not want converted.

The ARC converter will skip over the de-selected files and add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag where necessary.

Comment: This worked for me after I did a clean of the project. Otherwise it kept returning issues with the files that I was trying to exclude.